# From what organization or document are connector symbols like this referenced?

Tags: pcb, schematics

[image: connectors]

So in this picture I am asking about the representation of the Plug and Jack. Where does the idea that the plug is rounded on the back side come from? I am trying to put together a best practices doc fo work and was asked for some backup as to who made that standard and I cant find an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure where those exact symbols came from. However you could use the ISO Standard:

> 01.080.40: Graphical symbols for use on electrical and electronics engineering drawings, diagrams, charts and in relevant technical product documentation.

From ISO.org

Found here [Link](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_ics/catalogue_ics_browse.htm?ICS1=01&ICS2=080&ICS3=40&published=on%22%3CLink%3E%22)

Or the ANSI Standard (Depending on your intended audience).

Answer (score 1):

[ANSI Y32.2-1975.](https://www.noao.edu/ets/Mechanical/Policies/ANSI%20Y32.2-1975.pdf)

First, your arrow symbols are not quite correct. They are not indicative of Plug and Socket as a Plug or Socket can contain Male (Point) or Female (Reverse Point or Cup) contacts. A PLUG is on a flying lead or cable, and a JACK is on a fixed part or assembly.

This came about during WWII. Pilot headsets, Morse Code Key Sets, etc. all used 1/4" Plugs. The rounded back on the Plug was due to the back cover having a curved edge so as not to cut operators, catch clothing, etc. So, the symbology stuck. This is the way I have always identified my connectors, and this is what I teach College students today.

Anything that does not normally move and/or is tied down has a JACK on it. Anything that can move and/or is removable such as a wire harness has a PLUG on it. They can both have either/or male or female contacts.

The closed Arrows pointing up / down came partly from a drawing of a complete cable assembly and indicated ONE PAIR of wires. Probably a headset symbol.